# Ionic Tabs not working properly when coming from same module

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-tabs, tabmenu

I have the case when have 5 tabs at the bottom( home, about, profile, lob/first, lob/second ). first 3 of them are coming from different module and they look great but the last two of them are from the same module and this ones are not ok , when you click on one of them both are selected as active, any suggestion ?

I know there is a way with separating them with different module, but can they come from same module ?

Comment: You'll need to had some code in order to get help (tabs and routing at least). Check your routing modules.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.